# JSF session disappear after refreshing the page

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I tried to save an `id` and a `name` in a JSF Session but they are not being stored.

When I refresh the page it disappears.
This is the code I'm using:

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
session.setAttribute("id", 123);
session.setAttribute("name", "a name");
```

what i want to do by session is securing my pages using a Filter and inside it im testing if the session existe or not

Please help me

Regards

Comment: please someone answer me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem :D

I had a session scoped ManagedBean that was disappearing when the page was refreshed. So the problem is that the session was expiring after 1s or less. So I set the `setSessionMaxInactiveInterval` to `-1` which disables the session expiration timeout:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext()
            .setSessionMaxInactiveInterval(-1);
```